# Cannot restore database backup ("database might be in use" even after shutdown)

Tags: database, firebird, firebird2.1

I'm following the example on this site: http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/gbak-recipies.html

More specifically the following three commands:

```
tux> gbak -backup employee /backups/employee.fbk
tux> gfix -shut -tran 60 employee
tux> gbak -replace /backups/employee.fbk employee
```

I have replaced the commands to conform to my data structure, and the commands are then as following:

```
gbak.exe -user SYSDBA -pas masterkey -backup C:\Database\MyDB.fdb C:\Temp\DbBackup.fbk
gfix -user SYSDBA -pas masterkey -shut single -force 0 "C:\Database\MyDB.fdb"
gbak -user SYSDBA -pas masterkey -replace C:\Temp\DbBackup.fbk C:\Database\MyDB.fdb
```

The backup is created to C:\Temp.
Some times the shutdown command doesn't work and I fixed that by ensuring the database is actually online before shutting it down:

```
gfix -user SYSDBA -pas masterkey -online C:\Database\MyDB.fdb
```

However, even though there are no errors when shutting down the database, the restore always complains that:

```
gbak: ERROR:could not drop database c:\Database\MyDB.fdb (database might be in use)
gbak:Exiting before completion due to errors
```

Why is it doing this when the database has been shut down?

---

I also tried shutting down the database with `full` instead of `single`. The restore then gives the following error instead:

```
gbak: ERROR:invalid database handle (no active connection)
gbak:Exiting before completion due to errors
gbak: ERROR:invalid database handle (no active connection)
```

Which I guess is because the database is fully shut down and allows no connections, so one less thing to check.

Answer (score 2):

I believe shutdown function is not immediate, even if you use 0 minute.
You must wait several seconds to allow Firebird to release the file between the shutdown and the restore.

Anyway, I recommend not restore the database on itself. If there is a problem during backup or restore, you lose the database.
You should restore in a different name, rename the original file, and then rename the restored database.

Comment: How long does the shutdown function normally take? I've waited 5 minutes after the shutdown command and still I get the "in use" message.

Comment: Also, even after a full shutdown the file is still in use because I cannot move or rename the database file.